# How to get the value of searchbar in infinite scroll function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

```
  searchPublikasi(ev: any) {
// set val to the value of the searchbar
let val = ev.target.value;
this.publicationList.searchPublikasi(val).subscribe((publicationListData:any) => {
        this.allPublication= publicationListData.data;
        this.listDomain=this.allPublication[1];
  })
```

}

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
  console.log('Begin async operation');
this.page = this.page+1;
// set val to the value of the searchbar
let val = 'penduduk';
  setTimeout(() => {
  this.publicationList.searchPublikasi(val).subscribe((publicationListData:any) => {
    for (let pub of publicationListData.data[1]) {
    this.listDomain.push(pub)
    }
  });
  console.log('Async operation has ended');
  infiniteScroll.complete();
  }, 1000)
```

}

```
  <span *ngFor="let list of allPublication" color="dark">
  <ion-label style="font-size: 1rem;text-align: right;padding-right: 2%;">
    Menampilkan {{list.total}} Publikasi
  </ion-label>
  <ion-grid *ngFor="let pub of listDomain">
    <ion-card (click)="launchPubDetailsPage(pub)">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="1">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-thumbnail>
              <ion-img [src]="pub.cover"></ion-img>
            </ion-thumbnail>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="11" style="font-weight: bold;">
          <ion-label color="danger" style="font-size: 1.1rem;">{{pub.rl_date}}</ion-label>
          {{pub.title}}
          <ion-label color="secondary" style="font-size: 1.1rem;">{{pub.size}}</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-grid>
```

<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">

I really confused, how to get the value that user input in search bar and used it in doInfinite. When load the next page in infinitescroll show error. I can't use the keyword in ion search in doInfinite function. Thanks.

Comment: Declare outside variable instead of function.

Comment: Can you help me with example of the code, thanks before

Comment: can you shows us how do you have implemented search bar with your listing

Answer (score 0):

`ts code`

```
public searchVal = '';
constructor(){}

searchPublikasi(ev: any) {
// set val to the value of the searchbar
this.searchVal = ev.target ? ev.target.value : ev;

this.publicationList.searchPublikasi(val).subscribe((publicationListData:any) => {
        this.allPublication= publicationListData.data;
        this.listDomain=this.allPublication[1];
  })

doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
  console.log('Begin async operation');
this.page = this.page+1;
// set val to the value of the searchbar
let val = 'penduduk'; // or you can user direct this.searchVal

  setTimeout(() => {
  this.publicationList.searchPublikasi(val).subscribe((publicationListData:any) => {
    for (let pub of publicationListData.data[1]) {
    this.listDomain.push(pub)
    }
  });
  console.log('Async operation has ended');
  infiniteScroll.complete();
  }, 1000)
  }
```